# Dynamically display iframe based on database query in angular fire, unsafe value, domsanitation

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, data-binding, xss

Currently using ionic/angular-fire to create a daily readings app that will dynamically display an iframe for embedded YT video depending on the date. Everything works fine until I attempt to use data bindings in the src url for the iframe instead of a test static url. I receive the error: Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)

I researched this site and learned about DomSanitizer and SafeResourceUrl. My problem is because I am using an observable to fetch the url data and all other data about the reading (title, description, ect) I am lost as to how to implement this strategy. All examples here seem to be working with static url's or using different method (vanilla js vs angular/typescript way). I am terrible at figuring out vanilla to angular as I come from a PHP background but really want to switch to FAng stack.

I tried to include the script for DomSanitizer as per angular specs and suggestions here on SO, but because of the observable I guess, nothing seems to work and I get errors and IDE complaints.

Here is what i did trying to implement the dynamic url since i couldn't figure out how to include in the in the getReadings function (i figure this is completely wrong strategy but like i said i'm lost):
data-service.ts file:

```
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    import { Firestore, collection, collectionData, doc, docData, addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc, query, orderBy, limit } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Readings {
  id?: string;
  orderNo?: number;
  parshah?: string;
  date?: string;
  videoTorah?: string;
  torahPortion?: string;
  url?: string;
  safeUrl?: string;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  url: string;
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(
    private firestore: Firestore,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }
  getReadings(): Observable<Readings[]> {
    const readingsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'readings');
    const q = query(readingsRef, orderBy('orderNo'), limit(3));
    return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Readings[]>;
  }
  getUrl(readings: Readings): SafeResourceUrl {
    this.getReadings();
    this.url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + readings.videoTorah;
    this.urlSafe = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
    return this.urlSafe;
  }
}
```

In my home.page.ts i added this line to my constructor:

```
 this.dataService.getReadings().subscribe(res => {
        this.readings = res;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
        this.dataService.getUrl();
```

my home.page.html originally called the url like this:

```
   <iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="readings.videoTorah" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

now its:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let reading of readings">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="getUrl()" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <ion-label>
      {{ reading.orderNo }}  {{ reading.parshah }} {{ reading.torahPortion }}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but now I am just unsure how to do the entire thing after src="getUrl()" didn't work. I am probably completely out in left field now but this is a hobby and I just need some guidance please? I just know I am missing something really simple due to my lack of formal education in coding. None of my udemy classes covered this sort of thing, and yes, i am going back and studying more on typescript and rxjs because I get stuck on these a lot.

Comment: I am still stumped, and after some reviewing classes on rxjs and typescript and console.logging the urlSafe variable. When I console log the variable I get the correct url. There is no longer the unsafe url error, but it still does not display the embedded video. The url works outside of angular. Any suggestions for further debugging? Before I tried console log i was convinced my function was just badly written, but now i know it works at least up to getting the safe url. I just cannot figure out where to go from here.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: No. I moved on and will come back to this problem later. I lost days to this for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is very particular in how it accepts `SafeResource`s. These won't work:

```html
<iframe src={{url}}>
```

```html
<iframe [src]="method()">
```

The only way I got it to work was to bind to a property containing the `SafeResource`. But that's too restrictive. I want to properly use Angular with Observables and the async pipe and `OnPush` change detection.

To enable this I created a safe pipe. It's used like this:

```html
  <iframe
    *ngIf="iFrameSrc$ | async as url"
    [src]="url | safe: scRESOURCE_URL"
  ></iframe>
```

- The `*ngIf` is neccessary because the async pipe returns `T | null` even if the source observable only returns `T`.
- `scRESOURCE_URL` is just `public readonly scRESOURCE_URL = SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL` in the component class becaues Angular does not allow accessing things defined outside of the component.

Pipe implementation:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
  pure: true,
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: string, type: SecurityContext.HTML): SafeHtml;
  public transform(value: string, type: SecurityContext.STYLE): SafeStyle;
  public transform(value: string, type: SecurityContext.SCRIPT): SafeScript;
  public transform(value: string, type: SecurityContext.URL): SafeUrl;
  public transform(
    value: string,
    type: SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL
  ): SafeResourceUrl;
  public transform(
    input: string,
    type: SecurityContext
  ): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case SecurityContext.HTML:
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(input);
      case SecurityContext.STYLE:
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(input);
      case SecurityContext.SCRIPT:
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(input);
      case SecurityContext.URL:
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(input);
      case SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL:
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(input);
    }
    throw 'Invalid SecurityContext';
  }
}
```